# How to create an sp returning a list of boolean?

Tags: sql, list, stored-procedures

I would like to build a stored procedure which can return the value 0 or 1 depending if the day of today is in the list of date. I did something like this (thanks to my stack overflow fellow) :

```
USE [AP_db]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_pull_holydays]    Script Date: 09/05/2012   14:21:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Is_Holyday]
    @Value varchar(50),
    @Result bit OUTPUT
AS
Begin
    If exists (select 1
                 from Holyday_Date
                where ISOCNTRYDESC = @Value
                  and dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, Holiday)) = dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate())) )
        set @Result = 1
    Else
        set @Result = 0
        Select @Result
    End
```

It works well for one value, bu my issue is to do it with 500 values. So my question is how I can just send a list of values and have in return a list of 0 and 1 ?

Comment: IMO you can return tables only via table value functions and not by procedures

Comment: What query do you want to run (i.e. what datat should be returned)? I don't see any obvious extension to your current query which would return more than one result...

Comment: Why is `Holiday` in the `Holiday_Date` table not already a `datetime` with a time component of midnight (i.e. why are you doing the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` conversion on it)?

Comment: it is Ms SQL ,  I want to run a query like :    exec [usp_Is_Holyday] @Value = 'val1,val2,val3.....,val500',@Result =1

Comment: What would `@Result = 1` mean here? That *one* of those values matches a holiday? That *some* of them match a holiday? That *all* of them match a holiday? Also, how is this procedure being called, and what version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return any select result from a stored procedure by not using an `output` variable like in your example, but by returning a resultset instead, like this:

```
create procedure testProcedure
as
    select * from Holyday
go
```

Don't know how you run your SPs, but this will return a result set just as any other query would; supposing the result of the select inside the SP looks exactly like #test table defined below, you can e.g. insert the result of above SP into a temp table:

```
create table #test(
  [id] int,
  name varchar(64)
)

insert into #test
    exec testProcedure
```